# Save Date format of "December 02, 2015 07:25:11 PM" in DateTime variable

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format

I have a variable

```
private DateTime? createdDate = null;
```

This consists of the date in `12/2/2015 7:14:37 PM` format. I need to modify the date format to `December 02, 2015 07:25:11 PM` and then assign this new format to the same `createdDate` variable. I was able to modify it using

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(createdDate, out date))
{
    string modifyDate = date.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

But when I tried to assign it back to createdDate it cannot save since type is string, and to avoid this I tried `Convert.ToDateTime` but this takes it back to "12/2/2015 7:14:37 PM" format. Does anyone know how can I save "December 02, 2015 07:25:11 PM" in createdDate variable. Thanks.

Comment: Dates aren't stored in a specific string format.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` does not *have* a format - it's just a point in time.  The format is relevant when you *display* the value.  *That's* where you need to specify what format you want.

That also means you can just use `createdDate` - there's no need to create a *new* date variable to represent the same date in a different format.

Comment: Another module calls this code and shows exactly what the value is in createdDate. In my case it is 12/2/2015 7:14:37 PM. They want me to update the format to December 02, 2015 07:25:11 PM without changing the type of createdDate. How is that possible?

Comment: The only format that matters for a `DateTime` is when you want to output it or save it as a string value. If the other module displays the date, then *the other module needs to change* and specify the desired format.

Comment: @Santosh _That_ module will need to specify the format when it _shows_ the date.  `DateTime` has no property that indicates a specific format. "They" apparently don't know how `DateTime` works.

Answer (score 0):

As D Stanley said, its just a value of time. how that value needs to be displayed is controlled by formatting so formatting is just the presentation.

May be you can write a property like this to make things easy for you.

The consumer of this property will get the impression they are saving a formatted date & when they fetch it, they'll get a formatted output.

```
   private  DateTime  timePoint;
   public string FormatedDateTime
    {
        get
        {
           return timePoint.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        set
        {
            timePoint =  Convert.ToDateTime(value);
        }
    }
```

Write me a comment in case of any issues